# Woocommerce shop page sort by random but with infinity scroll duplicate proucts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

code for sort by random is:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}
```

and this one for not duplicate products on infinity load by AJAX, without this same product can duplicate 2-3 times and for that some products not appear.

```
session_start();

    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

    function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

        $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
        if (empty($seed)) {
          $seed = rand();
          $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
        }

        $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
        return $orderby_statement;
    }
```

But the problem with the last code is changing everything on wordpress, woocommerce etc..
an exampe: on woocommerce orders list of orders also is random, if you click order by date still show random, so you see on first list, order which is from yesterday and 3rd order can be 3 minutes ago.

Comment: That's because your last code is being applied too widely. If you add the following line:  `if ( is_admin() ) return $orderby_statement;` 
right after `function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {`, 
then that will solve your problem for the most part. This ensures that the query is not executed in the admin area (backend)

Comment: Hello @7uc1f3r worked, thanks a lot